# Query for data slow after creating a CLUSTERED INDEX partition [Azure]

Tags: sql-server

On Azure SQL Server, I have created a CLUSTERED INDEX partition for a table with 7 million rows. Then my website takes more than 10 seconds to load data.

But if I don't create a CLUSTERED INDEX partition, my website takes around 6 seconds to load the data. If I use the same database which created CLUSTERED INDEX partition on SQL Server Enterprise and put it on a server located in the LAN, my website takes about 3 seconds to load all the data.

My sql query for create clusstered index:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PARTITION_MYDATA (CHAR(4)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
    ('1000','1001',...,'5000');
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME SCHEME_MYDATA AS PARTITION PARTITION_MYDATA ALL TO
    ([PRIMARY]);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyData_partitioncol ON dbo.MyData(ClassificationCode)
    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON SCHEME_MYDATA(ClassificationCode);
```

Could you tell me any solution for this problem? Thanks

Comment: If you share the execution plan of the query, we can tell. Otherwise, it is difficult to tell.

Comment: My sql query for create clusstered index:
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PARTITION_MYDATA (CHAR(4)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
 ('1000','1001',...,'5000');

 CREATE PARTITION SCHEME SCHEME_MYDATA AS PARTITION PARTITION_MYDATA ALL TO ([PRIMARY]) ;



CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyData_partitioncol ON dbo.MyData(ClassificationCode)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON SCHEME_MYDATA(ClassificationCode)

Comment: How many rows are returned? Does your query specify `WHERE ClassificationCode = ...`?  Upload your actual execution plan xml [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared the execution plan, based on your question, I think your partitioning is not aligned with the query pattern. Due to this, it is taking more time to get the distributed data. I would suggest you to partition the data with respect to query pattern, to take advantage of `partition filtering`. You are having partition aligned clustered indexes. So, data is distributed in the partitions. Read about [query enhancement for partitioning based on query parameter](https://logicalread.com/sql-server-partition-tables-query-enhancement-dn01/#.XIs7EqDhXDc)

> Eg., You are primarily querying data based on EmployeeNumber. Then,
> create partitions based on EmployeeNumber.
>
> If you create partitions on
> EmployeeSalary, then queries based on EmployeeNumber have to scan
> partitions to get the EmployeeNumber and partitioning filtering will
> not occur.

Another thing, with Azure, it will take more time, as the data is located in a remote data centers and network travel time is there. With Local LAN, it will be faster, as data is located locally.